# Validation Annotation using target=parameter is not triggering while target=type works

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I'm trying to do a declarative style of validation in a rest service I'm writing. I wrote 2 annotations, one which targets a TYPE, which works, and one which targets a PARAMETER, which doesn't. I'm trying to figure out why.

We're using Spring Boot to wire everything together. Given that the target TYPE works, I'm assuming that the issue is not with configuration but with code. I start with the following method signature for a method in a rest controller

```
@RequestMapping(
  value = "/{itemId}",
  method = RequestMethod.PUT,
  consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
  produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
  )
public ResponseEntity<Item> update(
  @PathVariable("basketId") @Valid @ValidateBasketIdParameter UUID basketId,
  @PathVariable("itemId") UUID itemId,
  @RequestBody @Valid ItemUpdateRequest request,
  HttpServletResponse response) {
...
}
```

You can see on the method signature the @ValidateBasketIdParameter annotation which is the one that isn't working. The @Valid on the ItemUpdateRequest parameter finds the annotation that I wrote and decorated that class with:

```
@UpdateItemValidator
public class ItemUpdateRequest { ... }
```

The 2 annotations are written almost identically. Here's the one that works:

```
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {UpdateItemValidator.Validator.class})
public @interface UpdateItemValidator {

  class Validator implements
      ConstraintValidator<UpdateItemValidator, ItemUpdateRequest> {
```

I then override isValid() and call it a day. The only difference in the @ValidateBasketIdParameter annotation definition is the class name changes and the @Target becomes PARAMETER. But that class never gets triggered while the one targeting the TYPE does. What am I missing or not understanding?

Comment: I'm looking for the exact same solution. This is the best I've found so far but it doesn't work for me [link](https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2015/08/29/validating-spring-mvc-request-mapping-method-parameters/) I think maybe the issue might be with the Hibernate Validator. Another post was talking about disabling that validator worked. Hopefully someone smart will get on here and tell us how to make this work. Currently I'm just wrapping everything in a pojo and validating that.

Comment: It felt like a smell, but we ended up wrapping UUID with a custom POJO and wrote the validator against that. It works but it feels wrong.

Comment: I completely agree. That is the same method we ended up going with as well. I know it's possible but it just doesn't work with our configuration for some reason.